# Is there a way to disable the top directory menu in the FileDialog in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, filedialog

I have file dialog, where I click "open" it will open the filedialog.  However, I need to restrict user to only select the files in current folder.  How do I disable the top folder navigation menu option for the askopenfilename function? so they can't change the current folder

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd 

def callback():
    name= fd.askopenfile() 
    print(name)
    
errmsg = 'Error!'
tk.Button(text='Click to Open File', 
       command=callback).pack(fill=tk.X)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you need to restrict the folder? That seems rather user-UNfriendly. I don't think tkinter supports that.

Comment: Write your own filedialog, I guess.